# Seam2: Page.xml and the view-id

Tags: jsf-1.2, seam2

while searching for a bug in a project i found many `page.xml` files, where the 'view-id' was showing to totally wrong pathes (old structure), or some had no `view-id` at all!

As far as i understood Seam it works like this:
i call in the browser.the `pages/index.xhtml`
then Seam looks if there is a `page.xml` with a `view-id` pointing to `pages/index.xhtml`

what happens, if in the `page.xml` are some navigation-rules and actions, but the `view-id` points to `pages/foo/index.xhtml`

And what happens to `page.xml`, where is no `view-id` at all?

The navigation rules, and the actions should never be called, because it is not connected via the `view-id`, right?

Comment: ok, i found out, that the view-id has nothing to do, it's still called the actions and the navigation, whatever the view-id is showing to.  for what is the `view-id` then needed?